# Ionic 2 - How do I get back to the start page of a given tab

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

My APP works with tabs, inside these tabs I have buttons that open other pages using `push`, when I click on tab 2, and click on a button, it opens the normal page, then I click on tab 1, and then click again in tab 2, but instead of showing the start page of tab 2, it already comes open with the page that I had clicked before ... How do I make it every time it clicks on a tab, it shows exactly the Page of that tab, and do not bring the page I had visited open? I tried using `this.tabRef.select (0);` Inside the tab.ts but it double-clicks on the first click of each tab, which causes a blink on the screen leaving it blank for a few seconds by calling it twice ... I tried `this.navCtrl.setRoot (HomePage ) ;`, but it takes the tabs off the screen, as it takes HomePage as the home page.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in child pages of tab:

```
ionViewDidLeave(){
   this.navController.setRoot(/*your tab page*/);
}
```

Comment: It worked, I was using `ionViewDidLeave()` with `pop` in child pages, and ionic was showing me a warning. Thanks :)