# ionic 2 Tabs go always back to rootPage

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

In my app I have 3 tabs. In the first tab there is a list that pushes to another page (inside the same tab, so the tabs remain at the bottom). When I switch to another tab, and I go back then to the first tab I am still at that subpage. 
Is there a way to go always to the root. The problem is that inside the child-page I have also links, so the solution on [Ionic 2 - How do I get back to the start page of a given tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42006047/ionic-2-how-do-i-get-back-to-the-start-page-of-a-given-tab) did not work for me, as he redirects me also to the root when I click open a new page in the child.

Any other solutions?

Comment: please post your code so that it will be easy for us to figure out the problem than words does

Comment: I understand, but what code do you need? All the pages that are involved with this? I have a normal tabpage, and that has 3 roots. If I click inside the first root (then I see the child), and switch then to another tab and go back, I see the child. With the link I have provided in my question it is possible to solve this BUT I have also children of my child-page. 

Is there a way to reset to the RootPage always?

Comment: Just so you can understand this better, I would suggest reading more on `NavController` [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/) to gain a better understanding of how it works along with view creation.  All of this is explained there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would be the best way to fix that, but it should work. Suppose this is the page that contains all the tabs:

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="chatRoot" (ionSelect)="onSelected(0)" tabTitle="First tab"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="chatRoot" (ionSelect)="onSelected(1)" tabTitle="First tab"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="chatRoot" (ionSelect)="onSelected(2)" tabTitle="First tab"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

And in the component code:

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

// ...

constructor(public events: Events) {}

public onSelected(index: number): void {
  if(index) this.events.publish('TabSelected');
}
```

So basically, we're publishing an event when the user selects any tab other than the first tab (index equal to 0).

The in the FirstTab, we can subscribe to that event, and use `this.navCtrl.popToRoot()` to close the opened pages inside of that tab:

```
// FirstTabCode
import { NavController, Events } from 'ionic-angular';

// ...

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public events: Events) {
  this.events.subscribe('TabSelected', () => { this.navCtrl.popToRoot(); });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.events.unsubscribe('TabSelected');
}
```

Comment: Why not `setRoot` in `onSelected` function?

Comment: Because in the `onSelected` method, we're in the TabsPage, the one that contains all the tabs. We need to pop the navigation stack from one of the child pages...